# I get this error, can someone help? Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Can someone help me pls? I can't figure it out ...

```
if (isset($_POST['prodotto_cat'])) {

$product_cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['prodotto_cat']);
$category_cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,     $_POST['categoria_cat']);
$details_cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,     $_POST['dettagli_cat']);

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM prodotti_cat WHERE     product_cat='$product_cat' LIMIT 1");
$productMatch_cat = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productMatch_cat > 0) {
    echo 'Mi dispiace, hai inserito un duplicato "Nome prodotto" nel     sistema, <a href="admin.php">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; RITORNA</a>';
    exit();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO prodotti_cat (product_cat,     details_cat,  category_cat)
  VALUES('$product_cat','$details_cat','$category_cat',now())") or die     (mysqli_error($conn));
  $pid_cat = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Comment: I do front-end only, in php I'm a noob

Comment: which is the 4th value ?

Comment: i mean , does the id counts?

Comment: it is not added automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert 4 values into 3 columns.  Observe:

```
INSERT INTO prodotti_cat (product_cat,    details_cat,    category_cat)
                  VALUES ('$product_cat', '$details_cat', '$category_cat', now())
```

What column should hold that `now()` value?

Either add the fourth column to the column list, or remove the 4th value from the value list.

---

While you're at it, you should also start looking into what SQL Injection is, because currently your code is potentially open to it.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) is a good place to start, as is [this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  While you are *trying* to prevent the problem by sanitizing input, that alone is not enough.  Instead of trying to prevent users from inputting malicious code, simply don't execute user input as code in the first place.

Comment: I removed the 4th value now() and I get this error now

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: @DanielZaharia: Then you're going to want to examine your new SQL code and find the syntax error.  Note also that it's very difficult to control the syntax of your SQL code when you dynamically build it from user input like that.

Comment: Too difficult, I'll just add another value :)), and about SQL injection, does the escape string it is not enough?

Comment: @DanielZaharia: Looking at your code is too difficult?  You're going to find programming to be pretty challenging then.  And yes, escaping the string is not enough.

Comment: I added a new value and it works perfectly! Thank you so much, bro! Have a nice weekend.